# php not working with SQL; empty result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a project where I store an id in a table, which is linked with a filename. Upon requesting the id, SQL returns the filename. Yeah, Redis would be best for this sort of thing, but I don't know how to get that working with PHP.

Anyhow, the following code returns an empty result:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","USER","PASSWORD") or die("Unable to connect to SQL server");                                                                                                              
    mysql_select_db("DATABASE") or die("Unable to select the database");
    $scaped = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT fn from links WHERE id=$scaped");
    mysql_close();
    echo $res;

?>
```

I know the key I'm using when requesting the page exists, but I get an empty result and no error. What's going on?

EDIT: I get:

```
Unknown column 'rytughguyig78iu786546789' in 'where clause'
```

Where the long string is my id. My where clause is as is. What's wrong there?

Comment: add `echo mysql_error();` before the `mysql_close();` line. what happens?

Comment: @tpaksu, still a whole lotta nothing

Comment: Wait. There is something. May just be stupidity. Hang on a sec.

Comment: type '$scaped' instead of $scaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your line

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT fn from links WHERE id=$scaped");
```

to

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT fn from links WHERE id='".$scaped."' limit 0,1");
```

and by printing out the record:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row($res);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: If you include the fetch_assoc bit, I'll accept, but it was a combination of two answers that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_result will return some sort of resultset object. so you need to:
1.) Check the resultset object has record
2.) fetch the result record from resultset
3.) print it.

sample like:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT fn from links WHERE id='$scaped'");
if( mysql_num_rows( $res ) >0){
    $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); //other options: mysql_fetch_object, mysql_fetch_row
    print $record['fn'];
}
```

links:
[mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), [mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php), [mysql_fetch_row](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Answer updated after your error message:
change $scaped to '$scaped' for string comparision

Comment: It would still be wrong this way because he needs `id='$scaped'` otherwise its still trying to compare id to another column

Comment: @legion: i admit $scaped should be encoded with single quote its data type of id is string, but since op didn't state about data of id, i assumed it as integer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`"SELECT fn from links WHERE id=$scaped"`

to

`"SELECT fn from links WHERE id='$scaped'"`